# Unity Slow performance on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, debugging, unity-game-engine

Unity 5.1.2 iOS 8.4

Ive noticed massive performance issues with iPhone 6 Plus

Tested on iPhones 4s, 5, 6 performance looks about that Running solid 60 FPS

[image]

On iPhone 6 Plus however performance is going down to about 22 FPS for some reason. Unity profiler simply shows longer time to render.
Here is the log for iPhone 6 Plus

[image]

Notice average frame time is higher and max frame time is doubled that iPhone 4s?

Im wondering if this is just me or the Unity bug, probably with Metal?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the iPhone 6 Plus?

Comment: Its been tested on 2 iPhones 6 Plus. Will have a try now. Thats kind of shocking if it work

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, I'd also recommend trying to build using Unity 5.1.0. Dunno if it's related, but I had an Android build run abysmally choppy with 5.1.2, yet ran smooth when I rebuilt with 5.1.0. And my 5.1.0 builds run smooth on my iPhone 5s using Metal for what it's worth.

Comment: Nope, restarting didn't help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have had this issue before, the iPhone 6 plus will use the metal graphics library by default. Unfortunately this is very buggy at the moment and actually slows everything down! Go to your player settings/Other settings and untick "Automatic Graphics API" and choose OpenGLES2, this is the most stable library at the moment.

[image]