# Can I set the iOS Graphics API to 'OpenGLES2' specifically for the iPhone 6s, and Automatic for everything else?

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, metal

My Unity iOS game is running into strange rendering issues (extremely low performance and bizarre drawing glitches) **specifically** on the iPhone 6s. Upon some googling it appears to be closely related to [Unity Slow performance on iPhone 6 Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873915/unity-slow-performance-on-iphone-6-plus).

I am willing to do do the change - that is, specify OpenGLES2 in the graphics API - and it may very well fix the problem with the iPhone 6s devices. But my concern is that it will be affecting **the other** devices (i.e. the majority) negatively. Perhaps it will run fine on iPhone 6s but now the performance will be worse on other devices that were actually working well with Metal.

So ideally, I want to set OpenGLES2 **only** for the iPhone 6s, and set it to *Automatic* for **everything else** because it was working fine that way.

The Graphics APIs is a priority list. If I set it as

```
OpenGLES2
OpenGLES3
Metal
```

It may fix the iPhone 6s, but I fear that the other devices will pick OpenGLES2 which may or may not make them perform worse. Then, if I set it as

```
Metal
OpenGLES2
OpenGLES3
```

I suspect that it wouldn't fix anything because then the iPhone 6s will simply pick Metal, which is presumably what it has been doing all this time.

What should I do in this scenario? Can I set the iOS Graphics API to 'OpenGLES2' specifically for the iPhone 6s, and Automatic for everything else?

To clarify, yes: I *could* simply test the new settings on all devices, but I would rather not change anything at all for them. I only want to change it for the iPhone 6s, because changing the Graphics API seems like a rather big deal.

Comment: I don't think so .. I guess you might need two different builds .. something quite similar was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54743213/7111561) but there seems to be no real solution I guess

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do it with this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidUnityPlayerActivity.html?_ga=2.88391515.1336029396.1607817401-1574614248.1598810258

See this thread for more details:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/auto-graphics-api-logic.876967/